# How to replaceState and persist state after refresh?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've noticed that when I do `replaceState`, then refresh the page, the state becomes null. What is the reason for this? What alternatives are there?

If I don't call replaceState, it's still there after a refresh.

I need to toggle a boolean flag from true to false, if that property exists in the state, but also to keep those changes when the page is refreshed.

```js
const location = useLocation();

console.log('state: ', location.state);

if (location.state?.test === true) {
  location.state.test = false;
  window.history.replaceState(location.state, '');
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a library for routing? If so, why are you calling replaceState by yourself rather than using the library methods?

Comment: @Mosh Feu We are using React Router v6 and I'm doing this in order to detect from which component the user navigated to the current component, and I don't want to pollute the URL with query parameters so this is the solution I came up with. I want to clear the state later because it affects some logic that should only run once, and then never again even after a refresh.

Comment: Router state just like any other client state (including react's) doesn't persist after refresh since it's dtored in memory. If you'd like to store data after refresh, you should store it in a persist storage such as local storage or session storage (or query param which you don't want)